# How do I provide the custom location for the automatically generated files in Eclipse RCP applicaton

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Currently we are developing eclipse RCP application. After the deployment when we try to execute the application the following directories gets generated automatically by eclipse under /home/user (under user home) according to the Operating System

- .swt
- .eclipse
- .oracle_jre_usage etc.,

Since we have limited amount of saving space in user.home directory we would like to move the above stated folders to the custom directory. Please let me know how we can configure to provide a custom location for these generated folders.

Eclipse version we use : Eclipse Neon
Java Version : 1.8

Comment: What is in your `.eclipse` direcfory? I have several RCPs and don't get this directory. You might also want to read https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1077328/

Comment: In Linux environment even sometimes I don't get **.eclipse** directory always, but in windows it gets generated and the directory like org.eclipse.oomph.p2 , org.eclipse.oomph.setup etc., which contains the cache data.

Comment: The link I gave is about the Oomph data in that directory. I don't use Oomph for my RCPs so I don't get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below lines to your `<product>.ini` file, it will change all your configuration generation to specified location

```
-vmargs
-Duser.home=<Your_FolderLocation>
```